# In CSS what do the square brackets mean when used in the value of a "content" attribute in this particular example?

Tags: css

In this Heydon Pickering article:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/semantic-css-with-intelligent-selectors/#combinations

Heydon says, "You know how you can get all object-oriented and use a selection of multiple classes on elements to build up styles?"

Well, actually, I don't know ...

What do the square brackets mean in the example he gives:

```
.new-window-icon:after {
   content: '[new window icon]';
}
```

Comment: Nothing, they're just an example for placeholder. They have no special meaning in CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that after searching for half an hour. But how does that show an example of "object-oriented"?

Comment: It doesn't. I think the tutorial you're following has been written (plus it's quite antiquated now). If you're interested in writing structured CSS, check out [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/).